# Mounting volume on docker-compose, but nginx container sees empty directory

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to run nginx with docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  custom-nginx:
    image: custom-nginx:latest
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always

  nginx:
    depends_on:
        - custom-nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
    restart: always
```

The folder gets mounted but when I look into it from the nginx container it's empty:

```
/ # ls -al /etc/letsencrypt/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Nov 21 18:00 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 21 20:07 ..
```

The `custom-nginx` Dockerfile is just

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I assume it has to do with my permissions maybe?

```
ls -l /etc | grep lets
drwxr-x--- 9 root docker    4096 Nov 21 17:43 letsencrypt
```

The `docker` group has rx on the folder recursively. The `docker` user on the host can see all those folders, and the `docker` user is running docker in rootless mode.

I was assuming that the root user of the container should see all files the same way as the docker user on the host machine?

What am I missing here?

EDIT: This is the content of `/etc/letsencrypt` on the **host**

```
ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/
total 32
drwx------ 3 root root    4096 Nov 21 17:32 accounts
drwxr-x--- 3 root docker  4096 Nov 21 17:43 archive
-rwx------ 1 root root     207 Nov 12  2021 cli.ini
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Nov 21 17:43 csr
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Nov 21 17:43 keys
drwxr-x--- 3 root docker  4096 Nov 21 17:43 live
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Nov 21 17:43 renewal
drwx------ 5 root root    4096 Nov 21 17:32 renewal-hooks
```

The container, inside its `nginx.conf`, only references `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain_name>fullchain.pem` which actually is a link:

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain_name>/fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/<domain_name>/fullchain1.pem`

But both `live` and `archive` folders seem to have the necessary permissions in my opinion...

Comment: Whatever content is in the host's `/etc/letsencrypt` directory should be visible in both containers, the bind mount hides both images' contents.  Does this match what you're seeing?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean. This should be a bind mount, but the container does NOT see the contents of `/etc/letsencrypt` - it just sees the folder (as empty).

Comment: What is in the directory on the host?  Are there existing files in the host directory that you're expecting to see?

Comment: Yes - I'll add it to the post. However, the post already explains that the directory has a special group (`docker`) and group-read-and-execute bits

Comment: `EDIT: This is the content of /etc/letsencrypt` - _on the host_? Please edit to clarify - 'edit' edits are generally not helpful btw :) ). If you're insistent that permissions are the problem (I refer to the above comment), have you tried sharing a more permissive folder?

Comment: I could not get it work this way. I managed to get it working by copying all `/etc/letsencrypt` into the docker context and COPY it in the `Dockerfile`

Comment: Yes I even tried 777. I could not get it work this way. I managed to get it working by copying all `/etc/letsencrypt` into the docker context and COPY it in the `Dockerfile`.
I used the EDIT pattern copying other users who do so. What's best practice?

Comment: `What's best practice?` - write for new readers :). `I managed to get it working by copying all /etc/letsencrypt into the docker context and COPY it in the Dockerfile` this strongly suggests the docker compose file isn't being used at all - do you, for example, have multiple? If you put a parse error in the docker compose file does it complain? How are you starting the containers?

Comment: a reference regarding edit edits https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255685/761202

Comment: Thanks. I deploy multiple containers, that's why I am using docker compose. One container is created locally via the Dockerfile, end `depends_on` a nginx container (custom nginx config). The other downloads a public image and configures it.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify points raised in comments (i.e. make it so the comment can be deleted as redundant to future readers) - don't half-answer in a comment :). It sounds like you've maybe simplified your problem for this question and eliminated relevant details..? That or are confirming the problem is not as described in the question.